# jQuery problem with a blur event

Tags: jquery, events, dom

Here's my problem:

I have a div element that when it's clicked, another div shows up. Now I have no idea how to make that wherever I click on the page, this div gets removed. I mean, I know how to remove it, but which kind of events should I have in consideration to do such thing!? I can't make it with focus/blur can I. I mean I tried and it doesn't work so I guess not. Probably it's very simple but I guess I 'm to new to this ...

Cheeers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add it to the DOM, you could also create a one-time click event handler and attach it to the document. Something like

```
// <div> has just been added to the DOM
$(document).one("click", function() { $('#theDiv').remove(); });
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ocimo)**. add **/edit** to the URL to see the code

Comment: thanks, but I just tried out that solution, and the problem is that one click event gets triggered at the same time I click on the first div.

Comment: it's because the event bubbles up the DOM after the `<div>` element is clicked. You need to `return false` or use `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

I saw a [different question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838512/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-this-jquery/1838550#1838550), but it incorporated a similar mechanism.

Basically you want to attach a click handler to the `document` but only fire it if the click does not originate within certain objects:

With this HTML:

```
<div id="menu">Click Me</div>
<div id="other-popup"> Wow, I have been shown!</div>
```

Use this (or something similar):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   var $target = $(e.target);
   // For all clicks except those in the menu or the popup, hide the popup
   if(!$target.closest("#menu").length && !$target.closest("#other-popup").length ){
      $("#other-popup").hide();
   }
});
```

`closest()` looks in the current node *and* the ancestor nodes for a match.